# Pull to refresh UITableView Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a pull to refresh setup. It's currently calling [self.tableView reloadData]; but It's not reloading my parsed Json data from the blogData method. Is theres something I'm missing?

My controller is like this:

```
//
//  ARTableViewController.m
//  WorldCupLive
//
//  Created by Adam Rais on 14/06/2014.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Adam Rais. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ARTableViewController.h"
#import "ARModal.h"

@interface ARTableViewController ()

@end

@implementation ARTableViewController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.blogPost = [[ARModal alloc] init];
    self.blogPost.jsonMutable = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (NSDictionary *post in self.blogPost.blogData) {
        ARModal *bp = [ARModal blogPostWithHome:[[post objectForKey:@"home"] objectForKey:@"text"]];
        bp.away = [[post objectForKey:@"away"] objectForKey:@"text"];
        bp.result = [[post objectForKey:@"result"] objectForKey:@"text"];
        bp.info = [post objectForKey:@"info"];
        bp.homeImage = [[post objectForKey:@"homeimage"] objectForKey:@"src"];
        [self.blogPost.jsonMutable addObject:bp];
    }

    [self randomBackgroundImage];

    self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0f, -10.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    // Initialize Refresh Control
    UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];

    // Configure Refresh Control
    [refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(refresh:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    // Configure View Controller
    [self setRefreshControl:refreshControl];

}

-(void)randomBackgroundImage {
    UIImage *image = self.blogPost.imageUI;
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    self.tableView.backgroundView = imageView;
    self.tableView.backgroundView.layer.zPosition -= 1;
}

- (void)refresh:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Refreshing");
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    [self randomBackgroundImage];

    // End Refreshing
    [(UIRefreshControl *)sender endRefreshing];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [self.blogPost.jsonMutable count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...
    ARModal *post = [self.blogPost.jsonMutable objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:post.jsonURL];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

    cell.textLabel.text = [[[[[post.home stringByAppendingString:@" "]stringByAppendingString:@" "] stringByAppendingString:post.bst] stringByAppendingString:@" "] stringByAppendingString:post.away];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = post.info;
    cell.imageView.image = image;
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.000 alpha:0.000];


    return cell;
}

/*
// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}
*/

/*
// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    } else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }   
}
*/

/*
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{
}
*/

/*
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return YES;
}
*/

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

@end
```

And my modal:

```
//
//  ARModal.m
//  WorldCupLive
//
//  Created by Adam Rais on 14/06/2014.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Adam Rais. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ARModal.h"

@implementation ARModal

-(id)initWithHome:(NSString *)home {
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        _home = home;
        _away = nil;
        _result = nil;
        _info = nil;
        _homeImage = nil;
    }
    return self;
}

+(id)blogPostWithHome:(NSString *)home {
    return [[self alloc] initWithHome:home];
}

-(NSArray *)blogData {
    NSURL *jsonURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.kimonolabs.com/api/2nfgfo2s?apikey=1a1f5f323969d5157af8a8be857026c2"];
    NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:jsonURL];

    NSError *jsonError = nil;
    NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&jsonError];

    NSArray *jsonArray = [[jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"results"] objectForKey:@"collection1"];

    if (blogData == nil) {
        blogData = jsonArray;
    }
    return blogData;
}

-(NSURL *)jsonURL {
    return [NSURL URLWithString:self.homeImage];
}

-(NSString *)bst {

    NSString *sentence = self.result;
    NSString *word = @"-";
    NSString *wordTwo = @"00.00";
    NSString *wordThree = @"01.00";
    NSMutableArray *bstArray = [NSMutableArray array];

    if ([sentence rangeOfString:word].location != NSNotFound) {
        NSLog(@"Found the string");
        [bstArray addObject:sentence];
    } else if ([sentence rangeOfString:wordTwo].location != NSNotFound) {
        NSLog(@"time is 23:00");
        [bstArray addObject:@"23:00"];
    } else if ([sentence rangeOfString:wordThree].location != NSNotFound) {
        NSLog(@"time is 00:00");
        [bstArray addObject:@"00:00"];
    } else {
        float floatOne = [sentence floatValue];
        float floatFinal = floatOne - 1.000000;
        NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", floatFinal];
        NSString *bstFinal = [str substringToIndex:[str length] - 4];
        [bstArray addObject:bstFinal];
    }
    return [bstArray objectAtIndex:0];
}

-(UIImage *)imageUI {

    NSArray *imageArray = @[[UIImage imageNamed:@"Algeria"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Argentina"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Australia"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Belgium"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Bosnia-Herzegovina"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Switzerland"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Uruguay"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"USA"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Brazil"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Cameroon"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Chile"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Colombia"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Costa Rica"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Côte d'Ivoire"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Croatia"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Ecuador"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"England"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"France"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Germany"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Ghana"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Greece"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Honduras"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Iran"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Italy"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Japan"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Mexico"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Netherlands"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Nigeria"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Portugal"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Russia"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"South Korea"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Spain"]];

    int random = arc4random_uniform(imageArray.count);
    return [imageArray objectAtIndex:random];

}

@end
```

Comment: If you use CoreDataTableView and you insert new data, the tableview gets synced automatically. I use Core Data whenever I use json data cuz they are similarly organized. Use iOS Development videos of Stanfard from iTunes Univeristy to learn more!

Comment: Modal and model are two different things. Here you mean model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call the -[UITableView reloadData] method you are telling the tableview to refresh ints content based on the source you already gave him, but he doesnt change the source. In some cases you refresh you datasource and you need to refresh the UITableView so you call the -[UITableView reloadData]. What you need to do is to first refresh you data and the refresh the view, so the view uses your new data.

Use the the same way you got the data from your modal to refresh it.

```
self.blogPost.jsonMutable = [NSMutableArray array];

for (NSDictionary *post in self.blogPost.blogData) {
    ARModal *bp = [ARModal blogPostWithHome:[[post objectForKey:@"home"] objectForKey:@"text"]];
    bp.away = [[post objectForKey:@"away"] objectForKey:@"text"];
    bp.result = [[post objectForKey:@"result"] objectForKey:@"text"];
    bp.info = [post objectForKey:@"info"];
    bp.homeImage = [[post objectForKey:@"homeimage"] objectForKey:@"src"];
    [self.blogPost.jsonMutable addObject:bp];
}
```

Then execute the -[UITableView reloadData], but now he is going to refresh using the refreshed data that you got from your modal.

If you need something else, comment.

Comment: is correct. `reloadData` tells the table view to query it's data source. That means `numberOfSectionsInTableView` and `numberOfRowsInSection`, and if they return numbers indicating there is data, `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is called to build the cells. All of these are data source methods - the data source is the *adapter* to your model.

Answer (score 0):

`-[UITableView reloadData]` doesn't actually reload your data. It tells the table that you've reloaded the data, and now you need the table view to reload.

So before you call `reloadData` you should do:

```
    self.blogPost.jsonMutable = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (NSDictionary *post in self.blogPost.blogData) {
        ARModal *bp = [ARModal blogPostWithHome:[[post objectForKey:@"home"] objectForKey:@"text"]];
        bp.away = [[post objectForKey:@"away"] objectForKey:@"text"];
        bp.result = [[post objectForKey:@"result"] objectForKey:@"text"];
        bp.info = [post objectForKey:@"info"];
        bp.homeImage = [[post objectForKey:@"homeimage"] objectForKey:@"src"];
        [self.blogPost.jsonMutable addObject:bp];
    }
```

Also as this chunk of code only uses information provided by ARModal, you should probably put it in a method in ARModal

Comment: "-[UITableView reloadData] doesn't actually reload your data. It tells the table that you've reloaded the data, and now you need the table view to reload." That is incorrect and misleading. It does reload the data - by calling the data source. It does NOT tell the table view that data *has been* reloaded.